# Latest 'snowflake-snowpark-python' version not working on Snowflake side?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I'm currently using the latest **"snowflake-snowpark-python" (version 1.6.1)** to develop things locally (I have installed it in a virtual environment and here it works fine).

The problem is that when I want to deploy everything to Snowflake and run some store procedures there (which I have been written with Python-Snowpark) I get the following warning:

> "The version of package 'snowflake-snowpark-python' in the local
> environment is 1.6.1, which does not fit the criteria for the
> requirement 'snowflake-snowpark-python'. Your UDF might not work when
> the package version is different between the server and your local
> environment."

Indeed there are some functions in "snowflake-snowpark-python" (version 1.6.1) that are not being recognized by Snowflake (on the server side). It looks like this is not updated yet in the server, so this is a major blocker for the project I'm developing.

Indeed I have check the latest version available in Snowflake using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DM_EOS_TEST.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PACKAGES
WHERE CONTAINS(PACKAGE_NAME, 'snowpark-python')
order by version DESC;
```

This is the result:

[image]

It's using a previous version 1.5.1.

---

How can I update the package to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary Solution**
(until the newest version gets included on Snowflake server)

If you need to use a new snowpark-python function implemented in a newer release but the server version is behind, you can instead use the 'snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_function' (doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.5.0/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_function), which basically allows you to pass any snowflake built-in function.

This will allow you to call any existing snowflake function even if it's not yet implemented in the "snowflake-snowpark-python" library version you are using.

---

Please feel free to go through this thread where I also posted the same solution:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/feed/0D5Do00000yMzG8KAK